# leap motion JS, pitch undefined

Tags: node.js, leap-motion

I have some hello world happening with leap motion using nodeJS

I want to know the pitch value for a hand, but is returning "undefined"

```
var Leap = require('leapjs');

var webSocket = require('ws'),
    ws = new webSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:6437');

ws.on('message', function(data, flags) {
    frame = JSON.parse(data); 

var controller = Leap.loop(function(frame){

    if(frame.hands.length == 1)
    {
        var hand = frame.hands[0];
        var position = hand.palmPosition;
        var velocity = hand.palmVelocity;
        var direction = hand.direction;
        var finger = hand.fingers[0];
        var pitch = direction.pitch;

        var type = hand.type;
        if(type == "left"){
            console.log("Left hand.");
            console.log("pitch ::"+pitch);
        } 

        if(type == "right") {
            console.log("Right hand.")
        }
    }
    });


    if (frame.hands && frame.hands.length > 1) {
        console.log("two");
    }    
    if (frame.hands && frame.hands.length == 0) {  
            console.log("apaga too");
    }
});
```

So, when i log my left hand i get

> Left hand. 
>   pitch ::undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe pitch is a method belonging to hand not direction, not an attribute belonging to direction [docs](https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/javascript/api/Leap.Hand.html). Have you tried `hand.pitch()` ?